# Is it possible to do pagination in laravel with groupBy in blade view?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm fetching record for multiple section in a view. To show complete data I am simply doing 
`$data = Data::all();`

Then simply getting counts for each section as required.
For example:

```
{{count($data->where('status', 'HOLD'))}}
```

For another section on the same view I want to show result with Groupy
For Example:

```
@foreach($data->paginate()->groupBy('user_id') as $byUser)
@endforeach
```

Then show the pagination
`{{$data->links()}}`

I have already tried by separating the result in the controller and Calling the data using different methods.

```
$data = Data::all();
$userData = Data:paginate(5)->groupBy('user_id');
return view('data.all', compact('data', 'userData'));
```

This is working well without pagination. After adding pagination I am getting below error.

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\data\all.blade.php)
```

Is there any way to work it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
$data = Data::all();
```

Here you are already executing the query, this means, a `Collection` instance is returned. That's why you can't use the `paginate()` method, because that is a `QueryBuilder` method.

Try this:

```
$userData = Data::groupBy('user_id')->paginate(5);

return view('data.all', compact('data', 'userData'));
```